# AudioUnit support in MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, audiounit, xamarin

Is there any real AudioUnit support in Xamarin/MonoTouch?
Some classes are mapped but most of it seems to be missing, so it's impossible to implement AudioUnit mechanics as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH1-SW1). Or am I missing something?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure Monotouch supports the processing graph natively. You may have seen this, but I'll post a link for reference:

To get started with AudioUnits: view the sample project "AUSoundTriggeredPlayingSoundMemoryBased" in the repository:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples

Comment: I must confess I missed this sample actually and it's quite helpful... Thanks!